# Is there a way to retain selected keys in Dictionary based on Set without having to write loop?

Tags: ios, swift

In Java, if I want to retain a set of keys of a Dictionary (`Map` in Java), I can perform

```
dictionary.keySet().retainAll(goodSet);
```

But, in Swift, currently, I need to perform the following

```
let goodSet: Set = ["good_key_1", "good_key_2", "good_key_3"]

for (key, _) in dictionary {
    if !goodSet.contains(key) {
        dictionary[key] = nil
    }
}
```

I was wondering, is there an easier way to perform the same thing in Swift, without having to write a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is something similar in Swift but you could make it a one liner using `filter`

```
dictionary = dictionary.filter { goodSet.contains($0.key) }
```